# Output nested array with variable length to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, data-structures

I've got a datasample that I would like to output in a CSV file. The data structure is a nested list of different german terms (dict) and the corresponding possible english translations (`list`):

```
all_terms = [{'Motor': ['engine', 'motor']},
             {'Ziel': ['purpose', 'goal', 'aim', 'destination']}]
```

As you can see, one german term could hold variable quantities of english translations. I want to output each german term and each of its corresponding translations into separate columns in one row, so `"Motor"` is in column 1, `"engine"` in column 2 and `"motor"` in column 3.

See example:
[image: Table]

I just don't know how to loop correctly through the data.
So far, my code to output:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # The for loop
    for x in all_terms:
        for i in x:
            for num in i:
                writer.writerow([i, x[i][num]])
```

But this error is thrown out:

```
writer.writerow([i, x[i][num]]) TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

Any hint appreciated, and maybe there's even a smarter way than 3 nested for loops.

Comment: use: `for num in range(len(x))` it's a list, you're using the words not the index numbers

Comment: Or `writer.writerow([i, num])`. Just a side note, why not just save this as a JSON file. it will load as the same thing easily.

Comment: @Jaba if I replace my line `for num in i:` by `for num in range(len(x)):` then only one translation is put out.

Comment: @Madamadam For `Ziel`, `aim` and `destination` will be in columns `4` and `5` respectively?

Comment: Also, can there be multiple `key`s in the `dict`s inside the list?

Comment: Oops, it's `for num in range(len(i))` supposed to be `i` not `x`

Comment: @hqkhan no, since it is a new (german) term, a new row should be started, so "Ziel" is in columns 1, "aim" at col2, …

Comment: How are we supposed to know when something is a new `german` term? What's the logic there?

Comment: So there are 2 rows that will start with `Ziel`? Please include a desired output in your test case.

Comment: @hqkhan added desired table layout

Comment: Wait, so you did want it to be on the same row? What's wrong with any of the two solutions below?

Answer (score 1):

How about the following solution:

```
import csv

all_terms = [{'Motor': ['engine', 'motor']},
             {'Ziel': ['purpose', 'goal', 'aim', 'destination']}]

with open('test.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # The for loop
    for small_dict in all_terms:
        for key in small_dict:
            output = [key, *small_dict[key]]              
            writer.writerow(output)
```

Output in `test.txt`:

```
Motor,engine,motor
Ziel,purpose,goal,aim,destination
```

I used `*` operator to unpack all items inside the dictionary's values to create a row for the `writerow` to write in. This can potentially take care of the case if you have multiple entries in a dictionary inside of `all_terms`.

Comment: I used `python3` for this. You are most likely on python 2. If so, there is already a solution by @martineau below

Comment: This one is a clean and simple one. I think, I will upgrade to python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it:

```
import csv


all_terms = [{'Motor': ['engine', 'motor']},
             {'Ziel': ['purpose', 'goal', 'aim', 'destination']}]

filename = 'tranlations.csv'

with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for term in all_terms:
        word, translations = term.popitem()
        row = [word] + translations
        writer.writerow(row)
```

CSV file's contents afterwards:

```
Motor,engine,motor
Ziel,purpose,goal,aim,destination
```

Comment: this code is working, if I omit `newline=''`, otherwise error: `'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: Madamadam: Sounds like you're using Python 2, and if so, you should have tagged your question "python-2.x". For Python 2 use `open(filename, 'ab')` instead.